# mpicc, mpif77 are not there

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have downloaded openmpi from

http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-x86_64/openmpi-1.5.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

And I have installed using rpm -i openmpi-1.5.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.

mpicc & mpif77 are not generated. How to generate those binaries.

```
Can anyone help me.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`openmpi-1.5.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` is the run-time portion of Open MPI. The compiler wrappers are part of the development package [openmpi-devel-1.5.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-x86_64/openmpi-devel-1.5.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html). This is also true for most libraries with RPM- and Debian-based Linux distributions (e.g. RHEL, CentOS, SuSE, Ubuntu, etc.) - the libraries are distributed as separate run-time and development versions. With Debian-based distributions the development package usually has the `-dev` suffix in its name.

The reason for that is that one often doesn't need all the development files if the library is only needed so that executables, linked against it, are to be run.